# Get a listing of all currently loaded classes in a given JVM instance

Tags: java, jvm, jvisualvm

It'd be handy to know which classes are currently loaded by a given JVM instance.

Is there some way to get them through JVisualVM, for instance?

Edit: I'm aware of the solution given @ [Java - Get a list of all Classes loaded in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm), yet I'd like to know if there's a way to do that through JVisualVM or some other tool. At the moment I'm working against a RCP application, and I'd prefer to not having to run the application through the `java` tool (I'm lazy, yes).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Get a list of all Classes loaded in the JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm)

Comment: Try YourKit Profiler: https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/classloading.jsp . There is a trial version that you can give a shot.

Answer (score 1):

You specifically mentioned using a tool to get this information, so I assume you were interested in non-programmatic solution. `jcmd` seems to be a good way to do just that.

This was already addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/72929356/9773982 but I wanted to add another subcommand.

`jcmd <jvm_pid> VM.class_hierarchy`      (previously mentioned)

`jcmd <jvm_pid> VM.classloaders show-classes`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `jconsole`?

Jconsole should be able to display list of loaded classes, see [jConsole Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).

See the **Viewing Overview Information** section, the screenshot shows number of loaded classes. Plus, you can see a tab called **Classes**, this is where the class loading info is.

Comment: It seems to inform me about the class count, not which classes correspond to which classloaders. Am I wrong?

Comment: Opps, you are correct. I did use see this feature somewhere though, will post an update once I find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with VisualVM:

1. $JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisialvm
2. Select your jvm app -> Sampler -> Memory -> click "Heap Dump"
3. Open created Heap dump -> click "Classes". Where is a search field at bottom.

Your are welcome.