# Getting sub class fields using super class using reflection?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a class as below.

```
public class Emp{

 private String name;
 private String age;

 //setters and getters

}
```

Have one more class below.

```
public class Student extends Emp{
 private int marks;
 //setters and getters
}
```

is there anyway to get the fields of a subclass using super class using java Reflection?
I need to get Student fields using Emp instance.

we can get super class fields as below:

```
subClass.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();
```

similarly can i get sub class fields using super class?

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not possible to get information about child classes from the parent class, since the parent class (rightfully) has no knowledge of which classes extend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory there is a very complicated and costly way by retrieving [all loaded classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm) and checking which of them are derived from `Emp` and contain the field. If the desired class wasn't loaded yet this may not help either.

Answer (score 3):

I may have misunderstood your question. Do you want to do something like the following?

```
 Emp e = new Student(...);
 [do something with e]
 foo = e.marks;
```

If yes, do it like this:

```
 foo = ((Emp)e).marks;
```

However, if you want to do something like the following:

```
 Emp e = new Emp(...);
 [do something with e]
 e.marks = ....
```

Then no, it's not possible, and I'd suspect your internal model of java's object model is either incomplete or flawed.

Comment: +1 I agree there may be some confusion here over how classes work.  Either the *instance* is a `Student` and so the reference can just be downcast, or it isn't and so there's no `marks` field at all.  Reflection doesn't come into it either way.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, you have to write a helper method to that.

You take a class and the field name (and possibly type) as parameters, then look for that field in the given class. If you cant find it, you take the class's superclass and repeat from the beginning. You do this until you either found the field, or getSuperClass() returned null (meaning you reached the root of the inheritance tree).

This example demonstrates how to call find and call a specified *method* on an object. You can easily extract and adapt the logic for fields.

```
public static Object call(final Object instance,
                          final String methodName,
                          final Class<?>[] signature,
                          final Object[] args) {
    try {
        if (instance == null)
            return null;
        Class<?> instanceClass = instance.getClass();
        while (instanceClass != null) {
            try {
                final Method method = instanceClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, signature);
                if (!method.isAccessible())
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                return method.invoke(instance, args);
            } catch (final NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // ignore
            }
            instanceClass = instanceClass.getSuperclass();
        }
    } catch (final Throwable e) {
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want? But beware of using field.setAccesible.

Parent class:

```
public class ParentClass {
       private String parentField = "parentFieldValue";
       public void printFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
             Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
             for (Field field : fields) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    Object fieldValue = field.get(this);
                    if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
                           String stringValue = (String) fieldValue;
                           System.out.println(stringValue);
                    }
             }
       }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class ChildClass extends ParentClass {    
       private String childField = "childFieldValue";
}
```

Usage:

```
public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
             ParentClass pc = new ParentClass();
             ChildClass cc = new ChildClass();
             pc.printFields();
             cc.printFields();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the final solution!

```
    @NonNull
    public static List<Class<?>> getSubClasses() {
        StackTraceElement[] trace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        String method = trace[3].getMethodName();
        if (!"<init>".equals(method)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You can only call this method from constructor!");
        }
        List<Class<?>> subClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 4; i < trace.length; i++) {
            method = trace[i].getMethodName();
            if ("<init>".equals(method)) {
                try {
                    subClasses.add(Class.forName(trace[i].getClassName()));
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return subClasses;
    }
```

this are some examples of usage:

```
class a {
public a(){
print(getSubClasses());
}
}
class b extends a{
}
class c extends b{
}
```

And the result is

```
new a() -> []
new b() -> [b.class]
new c() -> [b.class, c.class]
```