# See all classes loaded by Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

Is there a way to see all the classes loaded by Weblogic 11g?  Is there any tools or utilities that may do this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Same as any other java process... see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm You can also connect to the server with jconsole and look at the full classpath if you don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Lear suggested this:

Run both of these as the user that java is running as.

If you are using JRockit:
/bin/jrcmd  heap_diagnostics

If you are using the Sun JDK:
/bin/jcmd  GC.class_histogram

You will likely want to redirect the output to a file.  It can be quite extensive.