# How to get a List of .Jar loaded in JVM Ibm AS400 (Green Screen)

Tags: java, jvm, ibm-midrange

I am trying to run a java program thats using a jar file in my Class path but I get an Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError dont know why, The jar is in the correct Folder On the As400...

My Question is how do I check what classes or Jar files is loaded by the JVM using the Green screen  ?

I tried using the command : `QSH CMD('java -verbose:class')`
but then get the following...

[image]

[More Info post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the "JAVA" command directly if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `java -verbose dummy`
This will fail to run the class named 'dummy' but it will list all the classes loaded.

IBM i reads the CLASSPATH only once in a given job, when you start the JVM.  So if you start the JVM and then change the CLASSPATH, new invocations of Java will still be using the old CLASSPATH.  Sign off, and back on.  Set the CLASSPATH (I do it in my signon program) and then try the class you're working with.

Comment: Thank you, when I try that command I get the following "ERROR:Could not find dummy Press ENTER to end terminal session" it fails like you said but no classes are listed?