# Java extend Application Classloader?

Tags: java, classloader

***Problem:***
My company has a lot of different jars/existing projects that they run at their customers. For debugging purposes, we would like to generate a log which class every component loads and more specifically: **from where**. For example: stack.overflow.ClassA in jar StackOverFlowJar.jar.

***My thoughts:*** 
I have experimented with passing each jar/existing project a custom class loader. This custom class loader could potentially write above information to a file, and delegate the normal flow of class loading to its parent.

My CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader, and I can see it loads classes such as:

```
java.lang.Class
java.lang.Thread
java.lang.ThreadGroup
```

etc etc, all the standard java classes from the core library. These classes do reach my CustomClassLoader. However, as can be seen by next image:

[image: test]
source: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html

There are multiple ClassLoaders. The Bootstrap ClassLoader (the one I extend with my CustomClassLoader) is only responsible for core libraries. If it can't find a custom created class, it will delegate it back to the Extension ClassLoader. If the Extension ClassLoader can't find it, it will delegate it back to the Application ClassLoader, and I can see in debugging modus, this is indeed the one that loads my custom classes. But it doesn't do so through my CustomClassLoader.

**My question:**
Is it possible to extend the Application ClassLoader and the extension ClassLoader? Or is there perhaps another workaround for my problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Work arounds: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2548384/3080094

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple Jar file, run that, using just that Jar in the classpath. You could then have a class that extends `URLClassLoader`, pass this object your real classpath, load your real main class through your ClassLoader, and invoke the main method using reflection.

Example main method

```
  public static void main (String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    URL[] classpath = new URL[0];

    LoggingClassLoader loggingClassLoader = new LoggingClassLoader(classpath, Main.class.getClassLoader());
    Class<?> aClass = loggingClassLoader.loadClass("com.company.project.RealMain");
    Method main = aClass.getMethod("main", args.getClass());
    main.invoke(null);

  }
```

Example class loader object

**Edit**

I have slightly extended the example, with there now being one loader per jar/ URL, in case you need to keep track of which class was loaded from what jar:

```
  public static class LoggingClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    final List<ChildLogger> childLochildLoggersders = new ArrayList<>();

    public LoggingClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
      super(urls, parent);
      for(URL url : urls) {
        childLochildLoggersders.add(new ChildLogger(url, this));
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
      for(ChildLogger childLoader : childLochildLoggersders) {
        try {
          return childLoader.loadClass(name);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ignore) {
        }
      }
      throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
    }

    private static class ChildLogger extends URLClassLoader {
      private final URL url;

      private ChildLogger(URL url, ClassLoader parent) {
        super(new URL[]{url}, parent);
        this.url = url;
      }

      @Override
      protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> aClass = super.findClass(name);
        System.out.println("Loaded from :" + url + " class: " + name);
        return aClass;
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: This might be a very good idea! I will try and work with this today, and if helpful, mark this answer as 'the one' :) Thanks!

Comment: Just add a comment if you run into any problems, or have any questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. In the end I chose to call every project with the verbose option and let it write to a file from command. Thanks a lot for your nice example though, I actually learned quite a lot from it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the

> -verbose:class

JVM option to print where classes are loaded from. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html