# Jar in the classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Is there a programmatically way to get the complete list of all jar in the classpath ?

I need that because we have behavior differences between two platforms.
One is managed by us, but the other is not and i need to know if there is
or not the same jar.

Comment: `java -verbose:class` might help seing what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a programmatically way to get the complete list of all jar in
>   the classpath ?

This is one way to [print out the current project classpath](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/):

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
java.net.URL[] urls = ((java.net.URLClassLoader)cl).getURLs();
for (java.net.URL url: urls) {
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```

If you need to [determine which jar a class is loaded from](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/how-to-determine-which-jar-a-class-is-loaded-from/190):

```
Class klass = ClassInTrouble.class;
CodeSource source = klass.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
System.out.println(source == null ? klass : source.getLocation());
```

You can also [get a list of all classes loaded in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm), if that's useful.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what do you exactly mean by classpath, there are in fact **different kinds of classpaths**:

1. **Boot Classpath**

   ```
   System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path")
   ```
2. **Extension Classpath**

   ```
   System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")
   ```
3. **User defined Classpath**

   ```
   System.getProperty("java.class.path")
   ```

Which works for standard Java SE applications. For modular and Java SE it is more complicated.