# Different number of class loaded on two nodes of Liferay Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, liferay, classloader

I have two Liferay servers running (Cluster) on two different tomcat on two systems.

Problem is both are started at the same time but when I see with visualvm number of classes loaded shows different value.

- On Node 1 --> 100000+ classes loaded
- On Node 2 --> 50000+ classes loaded

Here note that I have all the java memory parameters configuration,system configuration,also the applications(Liferay plugins) deployed on the both nodes are same on both server.

Want just possible answers why its happening? Is there any way how we can check what other classes are loaded easily ?
I know this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm) but it could be very cumbersome process.

Comment: And also when I check the permgen on node1 its using maximum permgem but on node2 its using half of the max permgen!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have cluster setup, I am assuming that you are using some type of load balancer infront of them. It might be possible that all requests are forwarded to one LR server and another LR server is used very  less.

Comment: I'll check and let you know.thank for the reply..we have check that already but no luck...but i'll try again.

Comment: Another possibility is that, you might have LDAP import or search indexing running on the 1st server.