# Find all Java classes used by an application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I have a Java application which holds two applications (a scheduler app and a receiver app). Since both have many common classes, we've developed this into a single app earlier. Each has different main classes with which we start the application. We now want to separate out the scheduler app classes and receiver app classes into two different applications.

How can I find and separate all the classes that are used by each apps to run?

I tried running javac SchedulerMain.java to see the classes loaded in the target folder to check all classes used. But is this the right approach? Is there another way or tool with which I can find the flow of classes from start of a main class?

Comment: Maybe dividing this application into modules in IntelliJ can help.  I can imagine scheduler, receiver, and common modules.  If you have all the code in a single project it will be easier to partition it.  Are the package names the same for the common classes?  That would help a lot.

Comment: Here's one option: https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Comment: The common classes are util classes which have methods used by both scheduler and delivery app. And I am not very aware about all the common classes used. I see some util classes in same package, but I need find a way to figure out the classes used by both apps

Comment: You could trace the classloading with `-verbose:class`, e.g. see [Get a list of all classes loaded in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm), but this will only report classes actually loaded, so you will need to be sure you exercised all functionality of the program. You will need to filter the output to only get your classes.

Comment: If you have IntelliJ ultimate - right click on a class, and select [Diagrams](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/class-diagram.html#manage_class_diagram).  Maybe there is a free IntelliJ plugin for Community version.  Eclipse IDE might have something similar.

Comment: Perhaps [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions. Since both my apps were tightly coupled, though I tried, it was difficult for me to use automated tools. So I started by creating 3 projects. Then focused on common util project, moved all classes and packages which were *Util. With this half of my project was sorted. Then I separated out scheduler and receiver app classes according to compile errors I got.
It was manual and time taking process, but I could sort out with better confidence. Thanks.