# Enforce maven use resource file in main jar instead of those in dependency jars

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies, overriding

Edit:

Structure:

A.jar(or A.war) 
  | 
  |_ src/main/resources/config.properties - (***mark as p1***) 
  | 
  |_ dependent jars 
          | 
            |_B.jar 
                | 
                |_src/main/resources/config.properties - (***mark as p2***)

- When I run A.jar (or A.war, since B.jar can be called either by a web app or java process), I want code in B.jar always use ***p1***;
- When I run B.jar alone, I want code in B.jar use ***p2***

Another way of describing this is a resource file with same name in the main jar/war (here it is A.jar/war) will always override it in the dependent jar(B.jar).

I check the source code of maven-shaded-plugin, it seems there is no guarantee that the resource file in main jar/war will be used. Does anyone have any idea? Or any plugin can do the work? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you may benefit from fleshing out your question and making it more clear to understand; in its current state, it's not very clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To an extent, this will depend on how B.jar loads its properties. If B.jar loads its properties using the mechanism:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties");
```

Then [Java's hierarchical classloading behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642606/java-classloader-delegation-model) will find `config.properties` in the places you are expecting:

- When B.jar is included as part of A.war then ***p1*** will be found
- When B.jar is run standalone, then ***p2*** will be found

I have a created a small test application (a war with an included jar) which confirms the above behaviour when executing the war and when executing the jar on its own.

When project A is not a war, but is itself a standalone jar (A.jar) then you're best to use the [Maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) to create a big A.jar. This plugin will include the contents of B.jar inside A.jar.

Using the filtering mechanism of the plugin, you can ensure that ***p1*** will be used. You can tell the plugin to exclude `config.properties` from B.jar

```
<configuration>
    <filters>
        <filter>
            <artifact>groupIdForB.jar:artifactIdForB.jar</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </filter>
    </filters>
</configuration>
```

By excluding ***p2*** as above, you'll end up with ***p1*** in the big A.jar

Comment: Hi Will, the properties do get loaded using getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"); the war case is expected as you claims. For the jar case, if I have a list of dependency jars containing this file, do I have to perform the exclusion on each of the dependency? Is there anyway to only keep the one in main jar and ignore those in dependency jar? Thanks!

Comment: The Maven shade plugin supports a wildcard syntax for use in the `<artifact>` tag - so if the dependency jars have a common groupId then you should be able to do something like `<artifact>groupId:*</artifact>. That should apply the filter to all dependency jars leaving just the config.properties in the enclosing main jar. There's more info on this [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html)