# Is it possible for class loader to get classes already loaded by different class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

I have class `Foo` which needs class `Bar` as an import. Class `Bar` is loaded with different class loader than `Foo` and while defining `Foo`, class loader can't find `Bar` and throws `ClassNotFoundException`. Is it even possible to tell class loader, if class is not available in current class loader try looking in another?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642606/java-classloader-delegation-model ?

Comment: it's tricky with classloader. Without a code snippet it's impossible to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not generally, no. One could write such a classloader, but you can't 'edit' an existing classloader to work like this.

ClassLoaders are asked by either code itself (`SomeClass.class.getResource` will end up there, as will, of course, invoking `findResource` or `loadClass` or whatnot on an actual `ClassLoader` instance), or by the JVM (when a given class needs another to execute, the class's classloader is asked for it. This usually results in that CL returning it from cache, but if it hasn't been loaded yet by that CL, that would result in it being loaded).

The CL is then free to implement this request in any way it sees fit. URLClassLoader, which is also the default classloader (initialized with the classpath) will first ask its parent loader (in the default JVM config, that'll be the system loader that knows where e.g. `java.lang.String` lives, from the jmod files of your JDK installation), and return that result if available. It will then load by scanning classpath, and it ends there. You can't ask an existing URLClassLoader to change its behaviour, but you can of course write your own classloader - it's just code, you can extend the `findClass` etc methods.

Maybe elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish. Why are multiple classloaders involved and what are you trying to accomplish by having multiple? (Say: Load classes from database BLOB fields, or, separate modules out, or, allow dynamic reloading of web handlers - that kind of answer).
Are you using an existing CL-based framework like OSGi, perhaps?

Comment: More precisely, the default classloader *was* a subclass of `URLClassLoader` prior to JDK 9. The default classloader and the system class loader (a misnomer) are identical. The loader responsible for `java.lang.String` etc. is called the *bootstrap loader*.