# my Eclipse just keep reporting errors but I don't know why

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, linkageerror

I installed an maven plugin to my eclipse but soon I noticed I don't really need it because I can just use external one. The Eclipse just started to give me some error like this no matter what I do.

```
>eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.8.0_20
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -Xms1024M
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data H:\eclipse -Xms1024M

>org.eclipse.jface
Error
Mon May 18 23:37:28 BST 2015
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

>java.lang.LinkageError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/CFlowCounter
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.computeDescriptor_aroundBody1$advice(JavaElementImageProvider.java)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.computeDescriptor_aroundBody2(JavaElementImageProvider.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider$AjcClosure3.run(JavaElementImageProvider.java:1)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.imagedescriptor.ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_imagedescriptor_ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect$2$80f5da8dproceed(ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect.aj:89)
    at scala.tools.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.imagedescriptor.ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect.ajc$around$scala_tools_eclipse_contribution_weaving_jdt_imagedescriptor_ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect$2$80f5da8d(ImageDescriptorSelectorAspect.aj:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.computeDescriptor(JavaElementImageProvider.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaElementImageProvider.getImageLabel(JavaElementImageProvider.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.JavaUILabelProvider.getImage(JavaUILabelProvider.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerLabelProvider.getImage(PackageExplorerLabelProvider.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.getImage(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.update(DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerColumn.refresh(ViewerColumn.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:949)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:114)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.doUpdateItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$UpdateItemSafeRunnable.run(StructuredViewer.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateItem(StructuredViewer.java:2150)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createTreeItem(AbstractTreeViewer.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:818)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:611)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1495)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(TreeViewer.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$4.treeExpanded(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1507)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.wmNotifyChild(Tree.java:7633)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5618)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1935)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:5169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4666)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1553)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_LBUTTONDOWN(Tree.java:6501)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4646)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:6024)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5023)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
```

I totally don't know what's going on now. Even if I deleted the plug-in, it didn't work. I don't really want to re-install Eclipse because there're some permission issues. Does anyone have any idea what this issue is about? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244482/how-to-deal-with-linkageerrors-in-java. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is related to JDT Weaving for Scala. I think uninstalling scala plugin should help.

Even today, I had the same error after updating scala plugin. When I've uninstalled the plugin, problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

If the use of external maven is causing your problem, try refreshing your workspace after a build with maven as Eclipse plugins sometimes don't recognize external changes to resources.

Comment: thanks for your help but I even changed a new workspace but the problem is still existing. Based on the error message, the problem is about "org/aspectj/runtime/internal/CFlowCounter"

Answer (score 0):

As added by Chris, Eclipse sometimes fails to recognize external changes.
After adding or removing jar/plugins make sure to do the following:

- Eclipse-->Project-->Clean
- Project-->Refresh
- Project-->Run As-->Maven Clean
- Project-->Run As--> Maven Install

Also its better to have

- Eclipse-->Project-->Build Automatically,
  which generally resolves such change issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help but now what ever I do, the eclipse always give me aspectj inernal CFlowCounter error........... I'm thinking to just give up the this eclipse now.......