# How to resolve LinkageError with JasperReports (6.*)?

Tags: eclipse, jasper-reports, slf4j

e.g. we got:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: ...
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: 
  Error evaluating expression for source text: 
    $P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.setTestRaw_LogOn_TstMsgOn(true, true)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader 
  (instance of java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader) previously initiated loading 
  for a different type with name "org/slf4j/Logger"
```

running in **Eclipse (Kepler) Preview with JR plugin v6.1.0**, but **not with another Eclipse running with 5.5.1.final**

Obviously we are using some build-path-referenced custom report scriptlet which itself is using the slf4j api for logging.

It seems to be conflicting with another different version of the same class (for the same underlying class loading isolation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Whoo ... finally at least an acceptable **workaround** for this obviously ***groovy class loading problem*** had been found)

We created some very simple **helper report `hlprep.jrxml`** that itself

- uses the mentioned scriptlet

  - or would use/call any other java class you would have problems with
- set it to `language=java`

  - (other sites recommended to switch from `language=groovy` to `java` to get rid of the above error, but that is often not an option)

(Now it should run fine in `Preview`)

**Every time you experience this error** (it may be random since the class loading may have been correct, depending on what you did before in your IDE) we can now do the following:

1. **open the `hlprep.jrxml`**

   - at best with `Open with ... JasperReports Preview` (so you do not have to explicitely open the Preview in further steps)
2. **restart** your Eclipse

   - it should remember your open files after restart, otherwise you have to open the helper report first after restart
3. **select/preview the `hlprep.jrxml`**

   - now the correct class loading takes place (triggered by the 'java' context)
4. **select/preview the (already open) other report(s) that fail(s)**

It **should run fine now, even after changes, but may fail if you open/close the new ones again**. (since the classes may get recycled or the groovy class loader isolation magic loads it differently)

## our environment

- *Eclipse Neon 3*

  - uses *Groovy 2.4.5* internally
  - starts with a *JDK 1.8.0_121*
- *Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.2.final*

  - we have a *6.3.0* server, but full Neon support was added in *6.3.1* so we took the last patch version of *6.3.x*
  - we had issues before where newer studio versions did not work with older servers so we are more careful with upgrades here
- may be irrelevant:

  - it was enough to just depend on the slf4j api (*1.7.12* in our case) in the `pom.xml`
  - we have both provided jasper libraries added to the project: `Jaspersoft Server Library`, `JasperReports Library Dependencies`
  - we also depend on server functionality so we also have `jasperreports-6.3.0.jar` in the `pom.xml` and some (not via some public Maven repo available) *server jars* as a `User Library` to the project (which we copied over from the server)
  - no groovy reference in the `pom.xml`

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and I solved it by adding those Jars in Build path in my project:

- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.12.jar

and add also the `JasperReports Library` and the `JasperReports Library Dependencies` to the project

with these steps

1. Right click in the project
2. Build Cath > Configure Build Path
3. go to libraries and add the jars using `Add External JARs`
4. Add the JasperReport Library and JasperReport Library Dependencies using `Add Library`
5. and then go to `Order and Export` and check the new added Libraries and Jars and click OK

you will get a result like that :

[image]

Comment: Cool. I can't reevaluate now, but my workaround above is not as nice as your solution seems to be, so I will accept your answer without having validated it. Thx for the nice solution! :-)

Comment: `JasperReports Library Dependencies` did the trick for us :) cool

Comment: but unfortunately I am stuck with another `LinkageError`: `java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;" the class loader (instance of java/net/FactoryURLClassLoader) of the current class, jr/utl/EnvScriptlet, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/loader/EquinoxClassLoader) for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/Logger used in the signature` ... investigating (jr.utl.EnvScriptlet does just use slf4j)

Answer (score 1):

The **easiest solution for us** (after some fiddling around with libraries and setup) was to **switch back to the Eclipse dir backup version with the Jasper plugin v5.5.1.final** (where we still had a copy of for all developers).

It was not easily possible to "Revert" via Eclipse Installation History since either our underlying update site only points to the latest or there may be no old update site for the 5.5.1.final at all. (we did not investigate further)

(btw.: it may be safe to disable auto-updates in Eclipse to avoid such surprises)

## Environment details:

(... to the likely causes for the ones who may find other working solutions.)

For us it's the usage of **org.slf4j.Logger** (having **slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar** and **slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar** in the build path or having both removed - does not matter ... just closing and reopening all reports after changes without Eclipse restarts)

Running Eclipse with the *eclipse.ini* jvm option `-verbose:class` shows that the conflict may be related to this other loaded class (whereever it is loaded (maybe used by jasper preview editor itself): `eclipse/plugins/org.slf4j.api_1.7.2.v20121108-1250.jar`)

I **suppose Jasper uses SLF4J since v6 and does not isolate its class loading of report-specific classes/libs** with a separate class loader from its own class versions (or the ones provided by the Eclipse installation) and thus such linkage errors (e.g. [How to deal with LinkageErrors in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244482/how-to-deal-with-linkageerrors..).) may be caused.

There is already a known resolved bug with 6.0.4 (where I added these infos) for this, but it obviously is not resolved:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/jaspersoft-studio/issues/3831#comment-818386

Comment: I struggled for several days trying to get other suggestions including the chosen answer to work, I could not. Your answer forced me to step back to a pre 6.0 release, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

A: **Sometimes** it's enough to **just restart Eclipse/Studio**. This may be related to some classloaders loading classes when doing certain stuff or using (indirectly) some plugins.

B: Also useful can be, to **try to exclude classes/jars** that are **(explicitely or implicitely) added to the projects classpaths**, user lib, Eclipse lib or Mavens `pom.xml` e.g., if the project itself does not use/need/reference them **for design time**.
This way the conflicts do not occur at design time/in Studio/Eclipse.
Maybe one has to keep in mind then, that **those classes/jars/libs may be necessary or different in the runtime environment**, which must be solved e.g. via `scope` in Mavens `pom.xml` or similar.